# How do I unit testing my GUI program with Python and PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, unit-testing, pyqt

I heard Unit Testing is a great method to keep code working correctly.

The unit testing usually puts a simple input to a function, and check its simple output. But how do I test a UI?

My program is written in PyQt. Should I choose PyUnit, or Qt's built-in QTest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145583/unit-and-functional-testing-a-pyside-based-application

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a good tutorial about using Python's unit testing framework with QTest [here](http://www.voom.net/pyqt-qtest-example) (old link that does not work anymore. From the WayBackMachine, the page is displayed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130903012954/http://www.voom.net/pyqt-qtest-example)).

**It isn't about choosing one or the other.  Instead, it's about using them together.**  The purpose of QTest is only to simulate keystrokes, mouse clicks, and mouse movement.  Python's unit testing framework handles the rest (setup, teardown, launching tests, gathering results, etc.).

Comment: Link does not appear to work. Maybe [this](http://johnnado.com/pyqt-qtest-example/) is the same?

Comment: @djvg Both links no longer work. Is there another link?

Comment: @a-hendry: Sorry, I wouldn't know, mine was already a guess.

Comment: The content of original the link can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130903012954/http://www.voom.net/pyqt-qtest-example) thanks to the Wayback Machine.

Comment: The code in the ref. page is available here: [https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample)

Comment: I am the author. The `johnnado.com` / `voom.net` blog article has been merged into the example code https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample to make a unified open source project. Contributors wanted!

Answer (score 13):

As another option there is also [`pytest-qt`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-qt/) if you prefer working with `pytest`:

https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

It lets you test `pyqt` and `pyside` applications and allows the simulation of user interaction. Here is a small example from its documentation:

```
def test_hello(qtbot):
    widget = HelloWidget()
    qtbot.addWidget(widget)

    # click in the Greet button and make sure it updates the appropriate label
    qtbot.mouseClick(widget.button_greet, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

    assert widget.greet_label.text() == "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is perfect tutorial where they use pytest-qt:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjctCBjHvmA&ab_channel=AdamBemski
https://github.com/adambemski/blog/tree/master/006_pytest_qt_GUI_testing

It is really simple, there is a code from the tutorial:

```
import pytest

from PyQt5 import QtCore

import example_app


@pytest.fixture
def app(qtbot):
    test_hello_app = example_app.MyApp()
    qtbot.addWidget(test_hello_app)

    return test_hello_app


def test_label(app):
    assert app.text_label.text() == "Hello World!"


def test_label_after_click(app, qtbot):
    qtbot.mouseClick(app.button, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
    assert app.text_label.text() == "Changed!"
```