# Pyqt unit testing

Tags: pyqt5

I have written small desktop app which save, quit and pop up window. I would like to write unit test for them I have gone through Qt unit testing but Qt unit testing has very costly unit test framework. is it possible to any opensource along with example to test functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unit testing my GUI program with Python and PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044447/how-do-i-unit-testing-my-gui-program-with-python-and-pyqt)

Comment: Python Wiki: [PyQt Gui Testing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/GUI_Testing).