# PySide2 not closing correctly with basic example

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyside2

When I run the basic script:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

forthe first time it all works fine. However, if I run it a second time I get:

```
File "../script.py", line 17, in <module>
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

RuntimeError: Please destroy the QApplication singleton before creating a new QApplication instance.
```

I am running the scripts in an Ubuntu machine. I get the same error in python2 and python3.

Thanks !

Comment: That works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably your IDE has already created a QApplication, so the solution is to create a QApplication if it does not exist:

```
app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None: 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```